# obtaining repository name using octokit ruby toolkit for github api

Tags: ruby, github-api, octokit

I'am basically trying to get name of my repository using octokit github api ruby toolkit. I looked at documentation and inside their code files:

```
# Get a single repository
  #
  # @see https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/#get
  # @see https://developer.github.com/v3/licenses/#get-a-repositorys-license
  # @param repo [Integer, String, Hash, Repository] A GitHub repository
  # @return [Sawyer::Resource] Repository information
  def repository(repo, options = {})
    get Repository.path(repo), options
  end
  alias :repo :repository

  # Edit a repository
  #
  # @see https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/#edit
  # @param repo [String, Hash, Repository] A GitHub repository
  # @param options [Hash] Repository information to update
  # @option options [String] :name Name of the repo
  # @option options [String] :description Description of the repo
  # @option options [String] :homepage Home page of the repo
  # @option options [String] :private `true` makes the repository private, and `false` makes it public.
  # @option options [String] :has_issues `true` enables issues for this repo, `false` disables issues.
  # @option options [String] :has_wiki `true` enables wiki for this repo, `false` disables wiki.
  # @option options [String] :has_downloads `true` enables downloads for this repo, `false` disables downloads.
  # @option options [String] :default_branch Update the default branch for this repository.
  # @return [Sawyer::Resource] Repository information
```

I understand that options parameter is a hash but I'am still a bit confused on how to specify the argument to get repository name. Here is my code:

```
require 'octokit'
require 'netrc'

class Base
 # attr_accessor :un, :pw

 # un = username
 # pw = password

def initialize
  @client = Octokit::Client.new(:access_token =>
   '<access_token>')

  print "Username you want to search?\t"
  @username = gets.chomp.to_s

  @user = @client.user(@username)

  puts "#{@username} email is:\t\t#{@user.email}"
  puts @user.repository('converse', :options => name)
 end
end



start = Base.new
```

with my acess_token I'am able to get my own or someone else github name, email, organization, etc, but when I use methods...they always have options parameter and I'm having hard time specifying the correct argument for this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll need to use the `repos` method instead of the `user` method:

```
require 'octokit'
require 'netrc'

class Base

  def initialize
    @client = Octokit::Client.new(:access_token => ENV['GITHUB_API'])

    print "Username you want to search?\t"
    @username = ARGV[0] || gets.chomp.to_s

    @user = @client.user(@username)

    puts "#{@username} email is:\t\t#{@user.email}"

    @client.repos(@username).each do |r|
      puts r[:name]
    end
  end

end

start = Base.new
```

For a full list of possible responses, see [the GitHub API documentation](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/#response).

I also made two small changes:

1. Put your GitHub API token in an environment variable (`ENV['GITHUB_API']`) instead of hardcoding it.
2. In testing, I got sick of typing my test username in by hand, so I used a command line parameter as the default with manual input as a fallback:

   ```
   @username = ARGV[0] || gets.chomp.to_s
   ```